# find indeces of grouped-item matches between two arrays

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.array([5,8,3,4,2,5,7,8,1,9,1,3,4,7])
b = np.array ([3,4,7,8,1,3])
```

I have two lists of integers that each is grouped by every 2 consecutive items (ie indices [0, 1], [2, 3] and so on). 
The pairs of items cannot be found as duplicates in either list, neither in the same or the reverse order.

One list is significantly larger and inclusive of the other. 
I am trying to figure out an efficient way to get the indices
of the larger list's grouped items that are also in the smaller one.

The desired output in the example above should be:

```
[2,3,6,7,10,11] #indices
```

Notice that, as an example, the first group ([3,4]) should not get indices 11,12 as a match because in that case 3 is the second element of [1,3] and 4 the first element of [4,7].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach making use of `NumPy view` of group of elements -

```
# Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45313353/
def view1D(a, b): # a, b are arrays
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    return a.view(void_dt).ravel(),  b.view(void_dt).ravel()

def grouped_indices(a, b):
    a0v, b0v = view1D(a.reshape(-1,2), b.reshape(-1,2))
    sidx = a0v.argsort()
    idx = sidx[np.searchsorted(a0v,b0v, sorter=sidx)]
    return ((idx*2)[:,None] + [0,1]).ravel()
```

If there isn't a membership between any group from `b` in `a`, we could filter that out using a mask : `a0v[idx] == b0v`.

Sample run -

```
In [345]: a
Out[345]: array([5, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 7, 8, 1, 9, 1, 3, 4, 7])

In [346]: b
Out[346]: array([3, 4, 7, 8, 1, 3])

In [347]: grouped_indices(a, b)
Out[347]: array([ 2,  3,  6,  7, 10, 11])
```

---

Another one using `np.in1d` to replace `np.searchsorted` -

```
def grouped_indices_v2(a, b):
    a0v, b0v = view1D(a.reshape(-1,2), b.reshape(-1,2))
    return (np.flatnonzero(np.in1d(a0v, b0v))[:,None]*2 + [0,1]).ravel()
```

Comment: once again, thank you for your answer. Have you got any guess on why `in1d`  might not work properly while `searchsorted` does with my actual sets in which I have already checked: all elements of `b` are included in `a`; paired elements are unique entries in `a` and `b`.

Comment: @Tony Ah maybe because the order of groupings in `b` isn't in the same order as in `a`. That is like maybe `b` is `array([1,3, 3, 4, 7, 8,])` instead of `array([3, 4, 7, 8, 1, 3])`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are grouping your arrays by pairs, you can reshape them into 2 columns for comparison.  You can then compare each of the elements in the shorter array to the longer array, and reduce the boolean arrays. From there it is a simple matter to get the indices using a reshaped `np.arange`.

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

a = np.array([5,8,3,4,2,5,7,8,1,9,1,3,4,7])
b = np.array ([3,4,7,8,1,3])

# reshape a and b into columns
a2 = a.reshape((-1,2))
b2 = b.reshape((-1,2))

# create a generator of bools for the row of a2 that holds b2
b_in_a_generator = (np.all(a2==row, axis=1) for row in b2)

# reduce the generator to get an array of boolean that is True for each row
# of a2 that equals one of the rows of b2
ix_bool = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, b_in_a_generator)

# grab the indices by slicing a reshaped np.arange array
ix = np.arange(len(a)).reshape((-1,2))[ix_bool]

ix
# returns:
array([[ 2,  3],
       [ 6,  7],
       [10, 11]])
```

If you want a flat array, simply ravel `ix`

```
ix.ravel()
# returns
array([ 2,  3,  6,  7, 10, 11])
```

Comment: thank you, brilliant answer. I chose @Divakar 's as the accepted one only because the `reduce(lambda ...)` takes quite a while for really large sets