# Check if all rows in one array are present in another bigger array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large `numpy` array

```
X= np.random.rand(1000,1000)
```

then I have a smaller `numpy` array, which in this example could be generated by

```
Y =X [[3,7,921],:]
```

I would like to check programmatically whether all the rows of `Y` are in `X`.

The solution should scale up well.
Possibly without requiring additional dependencies.

Inspired by: [Get intersecting rows across two 2D numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317022/get-intersecting-rows-across-two-2d-numpy-arrays)

So far I have tried:

```
np.all([s in set([tuple(X) for x in X]) for s in set([tuple(y) for y in Y])])
```

but my logic must be flawed since I still get `False` when it should be `True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach with `views` -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/45313353/ @Divakar
def view1D(a, b): # a, b are arrays
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    b = np.ascontiguousarray(b)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    return a.view(void_dt).ravel(),  b.view(void_dt).ravel()

X1D, Y1D = view1D(X,Y)
out = np.in1d(X1D, Y1D).sum() == len(Y1D)
```

Sample run -

```
In [66]: X = np.random.rand(1000,1000)

In [67]: Y = X [[3,7,921],:]

In [68]: X1D, Y1D = view1D(X,Y)

In [69]: np.in1d(X1D, Y1D).sum() == len(Y1D)
Out[69]: True

In [70]: Y[2] = 1

In [71]: X1D, Y1D = view1D(X,Y)

In [72]: np.in1d(X1D, Y1D).sum() == len(Y1D)
Out[72]: False
```

#### Benchmarking and alternatives

The proposed way seems pretty fast -

```
In [73]: %timeit np.in1d(X1D, Y1D).sum() == len(Y1D)
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.6 µs per loop
```

We can also do - `np.in1d(Y1D, X1D).all()`, but I think this would iterate through the elements of `X1D` for a match in `Y1D`. Now, in our case, it seems `X1D` i.e. `X` is a larger array, so this would be computationally more heavy than using `np.in1d(X1D, Y1D)` as with the earlier proposed one -

```
In [84]: %timeit np.in1d(Y1D, X1D)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.82 ms per loop

In [85]: %timeit np.in1d(X1D, Y1D)
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.1 µs per loop
```

Hence, the alternative solution would be slower -

```
In [79]: %timeit np.in1d(Y1D, X1D).all()
100 loops, best of 3: 5.99 ms per loop
```

Comment: This relies on a direct memory comparison, so it could produce unexpected results for -0.0 or NaN. Also, I think you switched the arguments to `in1d` in your first code snippet.

Comment: @user2357112 Yup, edited. For those corner cases, I would let OP get back to us, if there's such in their cases.

Comment: while you answer is correct, it would be really nice to know in which cases it does work... mayeb you could still edit the answer?thanks

Comment: @ErroriSalvo Not sure I follow - `it would be really nice to know in which cases it does work`?

Comment: @user2357112 said  it could produce unexpected results for -0.0 or NaN. That is a limitation...any other value for which it could produce unexpected results?

Comment: @ErroriSalvo Well `np.nan == np.nan` yields False. So, if you want to handle NaNs, you need to tell us the desired results. This solution should be fine for negative numbers too. Can't think of anything else.

Comment: thanks! I have added a minimal input validation to check for nans. Nice and fast solution anyway