# Numpy - Finding matches across multiple co-ordinates

Tags: python, numpy, self-organizing-maps

I'm using `somoclu` to produce an emergent Self-Organising Map of some data. Once I have the BMUs (Best Matching Units) I'm performing a Delaunay Triangulation on the co-ordinates of the BMUs in order to find each BMU's neighbours in the SOM.

In the following snippet of Python, is there a more Pythonic version of the `a == c and b == d` conditional? In other words, how can I compare `bmu` and `point` directly without splitting out the separate co-ordinates?

```
points = np.unique(np.array(som.bmus), axis = 0)
for idx, bmu in enumerate(som.bmus):
    a, b = bmu
    for point_idx, point in enumerate(points):
        c, d = point
        if a == c and b == d: # More Pythonic version of this line?
            print (idx, point_idx)
            break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We are working with NumPy arrays, so we can leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for a vectorized solution -

```
ar = np.array(som.bmus)
points = np.unique(ar, axis = 0)

mask = (ar[:,0,None]==points[:,0]) & (ar[:,1,None]==points[:,1])
indices = np.argwhere(mask)
```

**Approach #1-G**

One more compact way to get `mask`, which covers for a generic no. of columns in `ar`, would be -

```
mask = (ar[:,None] == points).all(axis=2)
```

**Approach #2**

Another memory-efficient approach for generic no. of cols would be with `views` and [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/45313353/ @Divakar
def view1D(a, b): # a, b are arrays
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    b = np.ascontiguousarray(b)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    return a.view(void_dt).ravel(),  b.view(void_dt).ravel()

n = len(ar)
indices = np.empty((n,2),dtype=int)
indices[:,0] = np.arange(n)
a,b = view1D(ar, points) # ar, points from app#1
indices[:,1] = np.searchsorted(b, a)
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the `.all(2)` accomplishing in the alternative `mask` definition?

Comment: @MattWenham That's short for `.all(axis=2)`, i.e. `ALL` reduction along  third axis.

Comment: Should that always be `axis=2` even if I am comparing more than two coordinates? Or should the number be equal to the number of coordinates being compared?

Comment: @MattWenham Yes, it would always be `axis=2` irrespective of the number of coordinates and also noted in the answer as - `covers for a generic no. of columns in ar`.

Comment: Gotcha, great stuff.

Answer (score 1):

With `numpy` arrays, you can use [`np.array_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html). This tests for same shape and same elements.

But if your logic is as simple as the code you have, use [@Divakar's vectorized solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49731025/9209546).

```
points = np.unique(np.array(som.bmus), axis = 0)

for idx, bmu in enumerate(som.bmus):
    for point_idx, point in enumerate(points):
        if np.array_equal(bmu, point):
            print(idx, point_idx)
            break
```