# Numpy - Finding matches across multiple co-ordinates - Revisited

Tags: python

I'm using `somoclu` to produce an emergent Self-Organising Map of some data. Once I have the BMUs (Best Matching Units) I'm performing a Delaunay Triangulation on the co-ordinates of the BMUs in order to find each BMU's neighbours in the SOM.

Using the information kindly provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49730895/numpy-finding-matches-across-multiple-co-ordinates), I have come up with the following line of Python, which seems awfully messy. Can it be shortened or otherwise tidied up?

```
points = np.unique(np.array(som.bmus), axis=0)
# Tidy up the line below?
bmu_idxs = np.argwhere((som.bmus[:,None] == points).all(axis=2))[:,1]
```

`points` and `som.bmus` are both two-column int32 numpy arrays where each row is a pair of coordinates. `points` will contain a sorted list list of *unique* points, and the object is to find the index in that list of each row of `som.bmus`. The output into `bmu_idxs` from the above is therefore a numpy array of the same length as som.bmus has rows.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50002023/edit) in some data which works with your logic, and also include the output you get?

Comment: I've edited and fixed a typo in the code. Hopefully that will help to set some context.