# Check number of equal arrays for 2 array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to check how many numpy array elements inside numpy array are different.
The solution should not contain list comprehension.
Something along these lines (note that a and b differ in the last array):

```
a = np.array( [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5]] )
b = np.array( [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,0,0]] )
y = diff_count( a,b )
print y

>> 1
```

Comment: Why 1? Two Elements are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Perform element-wise comparison for non-equality and then get `ANY` reduction along last axis and finally count -

```
(a!=b).any(-1).sum()
```

**Approach #2**

Probably faster one with `np.count_nonzero` for counting booleans -

```
np.count_nonzero((a!=b).any(-1))
```

**Approach #3**

Much faster one with `views` -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/45313353/ @Divakar
def view1D(a, b): # a, b are arrays
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    b = np.ascontiguousarray(b)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    return a.view(void_dt).ravel(),  b.view(void_dt).ravel()

a1D,b1D = view1D(a,b)
out = np.count_nonzero(a1D!=b1D)
```

### Benchmarking

```
In [32]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: m,n = 10000,100
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(m,n))
    ...: b = a.copy()
    ...: 
    ...: # Let's set 10% of rows as different ones
    ...: b[np.random.choice(len(a), len(a)//10, replace=0)] = 0

In [33]: %timeit (a!=b).any(-1).sum() # app#1 from this soln
    ...: %timeit np.count_nonzero((a!=b).any(-1)) # app#2
    ...: %timeit np.any(a - b, axis=1).sum() # @Graipher's soln
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.14 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.08 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.33 ms per loop

In [34]: %%timeit  # app#3
    ...: a1D,b1D = view1D(a,b)
    ...: out = np.count_nonzero((a1D!=b1D).any(-1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 797 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it using [`np.ravel()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy-ravel). If you want element wise comparison.

```
(a.ravel()!=b.ravel()).sum()
(a-b).any(axis=0).sum()
```

above lines gives `2` as output.

If you want row wise comparison, you can use.

```
(a-b).any(axis=1).sum()
```

This gives `1` as output.

Comment: Outputs `2`. Think OP wants to compare on per row basis and not element-wise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) for this:

```
y = np.any(a - b, axis=1).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
y=sum(a[i]!=b[i]for i in range len(a))
```

Sorry that I can’t test this myself right now.