# For each row of a 2d numpy array get the index of an equal row in a second 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two huge 2d numpy integer arrays X and U, where U is assumed to have only unqiue rows. For each row in X I would like to get the corresponding row index of the matching row in U (if there is one, otherwise -1). E.g., if the following arrays are passed as inputs:

```
U = array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])

X = array([[1, 4],
       [3, 6],
       [7, 8],
       [1, 4]])
```

the output should be:

```
array([0,2,-1,0])
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this (or something similar) with Numpy?

@ Divakar:
Your approach fails for me

```
print(type(rows), rows.dtype, rows.shape)
print(rows[:10])
print(search2D_indices(rows[:10], rows[:10]))

<class 'numpy.ndarray'> int32 (47398019, 5)
[[65536     1     1     1    17]
 [65536     1     1     1   153]
 [65536     1     1     2   137]
 [65536     1     1     3   153]
 [65536     1     1     9   124]
 [65536     1     1    13   377]
 [65536     1     1    13   134]
 [65536     1     1    13   137]
 [65536     1     1    13   153]
 [65536     1     1    13   439]]
[ 0  1  2  3  4 -1 -1 -1 -1  9]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Inspired by [`this solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38674038/3293881) to [`Find the row indexes of several values in a numpy array`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674027/)
, here's a vectorized solution using [`searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
def search2D_indices(X, searched_values, fillval=-1):
    dims = np.maximum(X.max(0), searched_values.max(0))+1
    X1D = np.ravel_multi_index(X.T,dims)
    searched_valuesID = np.ravel_multi_index(searched_values.T,dims)
    sidx = X1D.argsort()
    idx = np.searchsorted(X1D,searched_valuesID,sorter=sidx)
    idx[idx==len(sidx)] = 0    
    idx_out = sidx[idx]
    return np.where(X1D[idx_out] == searched_valuesID, idx_out, fillval)
```

Sample run -

```
In [121]: U
Out[121]: 
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])

In [122]: X
Out[122]: 
array([[1, 4],
       [3, 6],
       [7, 8],
       [1, 4]])

In [123]: search2D_indices(U, X, fillval=-1)
Out[123]: array([ 0,  2, -1,  0])
```

---

**Approach #2**

Extending to cases with negative ints, we need to offset `dims` and the conversion to `1D` accordingly, like so -

```
def search2D_indices_v2(X, searched_values, fillval=-1):
    X_lim = X.max()-X.min(0)
    searched_values_lim = searched_values.max()-searched_values.min(0)

    dims = np.maximum(X_lim, searched_values_lim)+1
    s = dims.cumprod()

    X1D = X.dot(s)
    searched_valuesID = searched_values.dot(s)
    sidx = X1D.argsort()
    idx = np.searchsorted(X1D,searched_valuesID,sorter=sidx)
    idx[idx==len(sidx)] = 0    
    idx_out = sidx[idx]

    return np.where(X1D[idx_out] == searched_valuesID, idx_out, fillval)
```

Sample run -

```
In [142]: U
Out[142]: 
array([[-1, -4],
       [ 2,  5],
       [ 3,  6]])

In [143]: X
Out[143]: 
array([[-1, -4],
       [ 3,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [-1, -4]])

In [144]: search2D_indices_v2(U, X, fillval=-1)
Out[144]: array([ 0,  2, -1,  0])
```

**Approach #3**

Another based on `views` -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/45313353/ @Divakar
def view1D(a, b): # a, b are arrays
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    b = np.ascontiguousarray(b)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    return a.view(void_dt).ravel(),  b.view(void_dt).ravel()

def search2D_indices_views(X, searched_values, fillval=-1):
    X1D,searched_valuesID = view1D(X, searched_values)
    sidx = X1D.argsort()
    idx = np.searchsorted(X1D,searched_valuesID,sorter=sidx)
    idx[idx==len(sidx)] = 0    
    idx_out = sidx[idx]
    return np.where(X1D[idx_out] == searched_valuesID, idx_out, fillval)
```

Comment: This approach fails for me, please look at my edited question

Comment: @user2224350 Yup was a bug indeed. Should be fixed in the edits just made.

Comment: hmm, I still get the same error. However, the third Approach works. This is really fast! Thanks alot!

Comment: @user2224350 That could be a case of overflow. Try converting the input(s) to `np.int64` dtype.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dictionary-based method:

```
import numpy as np

U = np.array([[1, 4],
              [2, 5],
              [3, 6]])

X = np.array([[1, 4],
              [3, 6],
              [7, 8],
              [1, 1]])

d = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(map(tuple, U))}

res = np.array([d.get(tuple(a), -1) for a in X])

# [ 0  2 -1 -1]
```

Comment: I guess this will be way to slow, because of the for loops. X and U have around several 10^7 - 10^8 rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use *broadcasting* in order to determine the equity of the items in a vectorized manner. Afterward you can simply use `all` function
over a proper axis to get the desire truth values correspond to expected indices. Finally, using `np.where` get the indices of where the equity
happens and simply reassign it to a previously created array filled with -1.

```
In [47]: result = np.full(X.shape[0], -1)

In [48]: x, y = np.where((X[:,None] == U).all(-1))

In [49]: result[x] = y

In [50]: result
Out[50]: array([ 0,  2, -1,  0])
```

Note that as it's also mentioned in documentation, regard broad casting you should note that:

> while this is very efficient in terms of lines of code, it may or may not be computationally efficient. The issue is the three-dimensional diff array calculated in an intermediate step of the algorithm. For small data sets, creating and operating on the array is likely to be very fast. However, large data sets will generate a large intermediate array that is computationally inefficient.

Comment: Why downvote? is there anything wrong with this answer that I can improve?

Comment: Just because the performance isn't the *best* isn't a reason to downvote. The point is the best answer rises to the top through upvotes. +1.

Comment: @Kasramvd Not me and agree with jpp!

Comment: @jpp This solution is completely vectorized but definitely might not be the best/ Actually nothing is the best lol. But regardless of that this is violating the SO's rule of downvoting. One should only downvote if the answer is wrong or not related to the given question.

Comment: I could guess that @Divakar ;))

Comment: This works fine for small Arrays. However for Arrays of size ~100k or bigger I get the following error message:
"..\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:12: DeprecationWarning: elementwise == comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  if sys.path[0] == '': 
...
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all' " (in the np.where call)

Comment: @user2224350 Regarding that error It seems that you're using arrays in wrong order but about the performance for large arrays as it's mentioned in documentation, while this is very efficient in terms of lines of code, it may or may not be computationally efficient. The issue is the three-dimensional diff array calculated in an intermediate step of the algorithm. For small data sets, creating and operating on the array is likely to be very fast. However, large data sets will generate a large intermediate array that is computationally inefficient.

Comment: @Kasramvd Not my downvote but FWIW I really don't think this "violates SO's rule of downvoting". You can downvote whatever you please. And when the OP's question's first line is "I have 2 huge NumPy arrays" your solution doesn't look promising.

Comment: @miradulo It does but that's not the point. You're right about *you can downvote whatever you please* and that's an obvious fact you **can** but that doesn't mean you should. Another point is that this solution is a straight and more understandable than other Numpy-based approach (no offense intended tho) and answer the question quite right but not in a blazing fast manner. This code has many advantages that one of which could be problem solving in a vectorized way plus advantages and disadvantages of broadcasting.

Comment: Sure. My point is just that your answer patently will not work for large arrays. Thus claiming someone is breaking rules by downvoting you is strange.