# Remove numpy rows contained in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, set

I have a numpy array and a list. I want to remove the rows contained in the list.

```
a = np.zeros((3, 2))
a[0, :] = [1, 2]
l = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Currently I try to do this by making a set of `a`'s rows, then exclude the `set` created from `l`, something like:

```
sa = set(map(tuple, a))
sl = set(l)
np.array(list(sa - sl))
```

or more simply

```
sl = set(l)
np.array([row for row in list(map(tuple, a)) if row not in sl]
```

These work pretty well when each row is short.

Is there a faster way? I need to optimize for speed.

Comment: look at `np.lib.arraysetops` functions

Comment: @hpaulj I see, `np.lib.arraysetops` is the simulation of `set` by sorting. But how is it compared to directly create a set in python? I suppose with long array and list, using `set` is faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Here's one with `views` (viewing each row as an element each with extended dtype) -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/45313353/ @Divakar
def view1D(a, b): # a, b are arrays
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    b = np.ascontiguousarray(b)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    return a.view(void_dt).ravel(),  b.view(void_dt).ravel()

a1D,l1D = view1D(a,l)
out = a[np.in1d(a1D,l1D,invert=True)]
```

If you need to have unique rows only in the output as with `set`, use `np.unique` on the output obtained -

```
np.unique(out,axis=0)
```

Sample run outputs -

```
In [72]: a
Out[72]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0]])

In [73]: l
Out[73]: [(1, 2), (3, 4)]

In [74]: out
Out[74]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0]])
In [75]: np.unique(out,axis=0)
Out[75]: array([[0, 0]])
```

**Approach #2 :** With the same philosophy of reducing dimensionality, here's with matrix-multiplication specific to `int` dtype data -

```
l = np.asarray(l)
shp = np.maximum(a.max(0)+1,l.max(0)+1)
s = np.r_[shp[::-1].cumprod()[::-1][1:],1]
l1D = l.dot(s)
a1D = a.dot(s)
l1Ds = np.sort(l1D)
out = a[l1D[np.searchsorted(l1Ds,a1D)] != a1D]
```

Comment: Thanks. But the code looks quite complicated and not easy to understand. I don't see the use of hashing in this. How does it improve speed?

Comment: @THN It improves performance by reducing dimensionality. Each row is processed as one "entity" each. There's no hashing here, not explicitly anyway.

Comment: I see, so `view1D` or `dot` is a way to reduce what needed to be compared. That can be set apart from the search later. Sort + binary search vs. Hashing is another problem depending on specific data. Thanks.