# Check if two 3D numpy arrays contain overlapping 2D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have two very large numpy arrays, which are both 3D. I need to find an efficient way to check if they are overlapping, because turning them both into sets first takes too long. I tried to use another solution I found here for this same problem but for 2D arrays, but I didn't manage to make it work for 3D.
Here is the solution for 2D:

```
nrows, ncols = A.shape
dtype={'names':['f{}'.format(i) for i in range(ndep)],
       'formats':ndep * [A.dtype]}
C = np.intersect1d(A.view(dtype).view(dtype), B.view(dtype).view(dtype))
# This last bit is optional if you're okay with "C" being a structured array...
C = C.view(A.dtype).reshape(-1, ndep)
```

(where A and B are the 2D arrays)
I need to find the number of overlapping numpy arrays, but not the specific ones.

Comment: Not sure if that's what you've intended but you can check intersection for each dim and then intersect the result

Comment: No. In my scenario there's an object in the second and third dimensions. I want to check if those objects appear in the other array, and if so how many.

Comment: How would you define if two 3D arrays are intersecting? Can you add minimal sample data?

Comment: What do you mean by "intersecting"? Mathematically, this concept only applies to sets, not to matrices.

Comment: The objects are images. the images are in 2D, and they are in an array. I want to check if some of the images that appear in one array also appear in another. Sorry for the bad explanation earlier

Comment: What's the output that are you expecting?

Comment: The number of overlapping images

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We could leverage `views` using a helper function that I have used across few Q&As. To get the presence of subarrays, we could use `np.isin` on the views or use a more laborious one with `np.searchsorted`.

**Approach #1 :** Using `np.isin` -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/45313353/ @Divakar
def view1D(a, b): # a, b are arrays
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    b = np.ascontiguousarray(b)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    return a.view(void_dt).ravel(),  b.view(void_dt).ravel()

def isin_nd(a,b):
    # a,b are the 3D input arrays to give us "isin-like" functionality across them
    A,B = view1D(a.reshape(a.shape[0],-1),b.reshape(b.shape[0],-1))
    return np.isin(A,B)
```

**Approach #2 :** We could also leverage `np.searchsorted` upon the `views` -

```
def isin_nd_searchsorted(a,b):
    # a,b are the 3D input arrays
    A,B = view1D(a.reshape(a.shape[0],-1),b.reshape(b.shape[0],-1))
    sidx = A.argsort()
    sorted_index = np.searchsorted(A,B,sorter=sidx)
    sorted_index[sorted_index==len(A)] = len(A)-1
    idx = sidx[sorted_index]
    return A[idx] == B
```

So, these two solutions give us the mask of presence of each of the subarrays from `a` in `b`. Hence, to get our desired count, it would be - `isin_nd(a,b).sum()` or `isin_nd_searchsorted(a,b).sum()`.

Sample run -

```
In [71]: # Setup with 3 common "subarrays"
    ...: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(10,4,5))
    ...: b = np.random.randint(0,9,(7,4,5))
    ...: 
    ...: b[1] = a[4]
    ...: b[3] = a[2]
    ...: b[6] = a[0]

In [72]: isin_nd(a,b).sum()
Out[72]: 3

In [73]: isin_nd_searchsorted(a,b).sum()
Out[73]: 3
```

Timings on large arrays -

```
In [74]: # Setup
    ...: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(100,100,100))
    ...: b = np.random.randint(0,9,(100,100,100))
    ...: idxa = np.random.choice(range(len(a)), len(a)//2, replace=False)
    ...: idxb = np.random.choice(range(len(b)), len(b)//2, replace=False)
    ...: a[idxa] = b[idxb]

# Verify output
In [82]: np.allclose(isin_nd(a,b),isin_nd_searchsorted(a,b))
Out[82]: True

In [75]: %timeit isin_nd(a,b).sum()
10 loops, best of 3: 31.2 ms per loop

In [76]: %timeit isin_nd_searchsorted(a,b).sum()
100 loops, best of 3: 1.98 ms per loop
```