# Compare 2D arrays of different size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 2D  arrays of different sizes.

The first array has 3 rows and 7 columns 
The second array has 60 rows and 7 columns

```
array_1 = 
[[0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
 [1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
 [1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0.]]
```

```
array_3 =
[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
 [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
 [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
 [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
 [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1.],
 [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
 [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
 [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
 [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
 [0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
 [0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
 [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
 [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1.],
 [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
 [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
 [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
 [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
 [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
 [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
 [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
 [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
 [0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
 [0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
 [0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
 [0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
 [0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
 [0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
 [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
 [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
 [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
 [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
 [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
 [1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
 [1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
 [1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1.],
 [1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
 [1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
 [1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
 [1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
 [1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
 [1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
 [1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
 [1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1.],
 [1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
 [1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
 [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
 [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
 [1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
 [1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
 [1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
 [1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
 [1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
 [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
 [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
 [1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
 [1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
 [1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
 [1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1.],
 [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
 [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]]
```

At the moment I have a function like this:

```
def compare(arr_1, arr_2):
    return arr_1 == arr_2.all(axis=1)
```

Which only return a `False` value.

What I would like for the function to do is to compare the rows in `array_1` with the rows in `array_2`, essentially seeing if any of the rows in `array_1` match any of the rows in `array_2`.

Ideally, a boolean array could represent this as follows: `[True, False, True]`

Basically representing that row 0 in `array_1` matches a row in `array_2`, row 1 in `array_1` doesn't match a row in `array_2`, etc...

Comment: I don't at all understand what your intended/expected output is. Your explanation in the last sentence is hard to understand.

Comment: 10 or 3, pick one please. Your question is inconsistent at best

Comment: Also, those are not binary arrays exactly. They're very wastefully using float instead of bool dtype.

Comment: Apologies, I edited the question, hopefully this is more clear now. Thanks.

Comment: `[(array_3 == array_1[i]).all(1).any() for i in range(len(array_1))]`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Any good reason on re-opening? That Q&A seemed to solve it.

Comment: @Divakar. Could you provide the link again? I was in a meeting, and I thought I had a good reason, but now I'm not so sure. Sorry about that.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Works for nd arrays, not limited to 2D arrays - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54791950.

Comment: @Divakar. Yeah, I don't think I had a good reason to reopen, even if I thought so at the time.

Comment: @MadPhysicist No worries. Things are back at where they shoud be. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function to solve this problem.
It will iterate through the first array, and check if that row exists in the second one, and finally storage the answer in the result variable.

```
def compare_arrays(arr_1, arr_2):
    result = []
    for row in arr_1:
        result.append(row in arr_2)
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to check membership with `2d` arrays, one approach is to view them as single dimensional arrays. So we can take `1d` views of both arrays and use `np.in1d` to find which rows in a given array are contained in another:

```
def view_as1d(a):
    return a.view(np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[-1])))

np.in1d(view_as1d(array_1), view_as1d(array_3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want:

```
[row in array_3 for row in array_1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with `all`, but you also need an `any` across the rows. You can acheive that with a new dimension and broadcasting.

First create a 3x60x7 array containing the matches between every row of `arr1` and `arr2`:

```
 m = (arr1[:, None, ...] == arr2[None, ...])
```

Then compute if entire rows match:

```
 n = m.all(axis=-1)
```

Now you can check if there's a full row match in `arr2` for each of the rows in `arr1`:

```
 result = n.any(axis=-1)
```

As a one-liner:

```
 (arr1[:, None, ...] == arr2[None, ...]).all(axis=-1).any(axis=-1)
```