# Select where a subset of columns in a pandas DataFrame match a tuple

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is a simple problem that I can't seem to find an elegant solution to. I am trying to select the rows of a data frame where two of the columns form a pair from a separate list.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(8), 'b': range(8), 'c': list('zyxwvuts')})
pairs = [(4, 4), (5, 6), (6, 6), (7, 9)]

# The data has an arbitrary number of columns, but I just want
# to match 'a' and 'b'
df
    a   b   c
0   0   0   z
1   1   1   y
2   2   2   x
3   3   3   w
4   4   4   v
5   5   5   u
6   6   6   t
7   7   7   s
```

In this example, my list `pairs` contains the combination of `df.a` and `df.b` at rows 4 and 6. What I would like is a clean way to get the data frame given by  `df.iloc[[4, 6], :]`.

Is there a `pandas` or `numpy` way to do this without explicitly looping over `pairs`?

---

#### Answer comparison

The solution using broadcasting is both clean and fast, as well as scaling very well.

```
def with_set_index(df, pairs):
    return df.set_index(['a','b']).loc[pairs].dropna()

def with_tuple_isin(df, pairs):
    return df[df[['a','b']].apply(tuple,1).isin(pairs)]

def with_array_views(df, pairs):
    def view1D(a, b): # a, b are arrays
        a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
        b = np.ascontiguousarray(b)
        void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
        return a.view(void_dt).ravel(), b.view(void_dt).ravel()

    A, B = view1D(df[['a','b']].values, np.asarray(pairs))
    return df[np.isin(A, B)]

def with_broadcasting(df, pairs):
    return df[(df[['a','b']].values[:,None] == pairs).all(2).any(1)]

%timeit with_set_index(df, pairs)
# 7.35 ms ± 119 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit with_tuple_isin(df, pairs)
# 1.89 ms ± 24.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit with_array_views(df, pairs)
# 917 µs ± 17.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit with_broadcasting(df, pairs)
# 879 µs ± 8.85 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vectorized one based on array-views -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/45313353/ @Divakar
def view1D(a, b): # a, b are arrays
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    b = np.ascontiguousarray(b)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    return a.view(void_dt).ravel(),  b.view(void_dt).ravel()

A,B = view1D(df[['a','b']].values,np.asarray(pairs))
out = df[np.isin(A,B)]
```

Output for given sample -

```
In [263]: out
Out[263]: 
   a  b  c
4  4  4  v
6  6  6  t
```

If you are looking for a compact/clean version, we can also leverage `broadcasting` -

```
In [269]: df[(df[['a','b']].values[:,None] == pairs).all(2).any(1)]
Out[269]: 
   a  b  c
4  4  4  v
6  6  6  t
```

Answer (score 6):

`tuple` with `isin`

```
df[df[['a','b']].apply(tuple,1).isin(pairs)]
Out[686]: 
   a  b  c
4  4  4  v
6  6  6  t
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`df.set_index(['a','b']).loc[pairs].dropna()`

Comment: Very simple but it's no longer supported.  The error message is:

KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'