# cv2.addWeighted except some color

Tags: python, performance, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I want overlay two images except specified color(it is black color in my case). I already wrote some code for this.

```py
def overlay_two_image(image, overlay):
    result = image.copy()
    mask = np.full(image.shape, False)
    for i in range(image.shape[0]):
        for j in range(image.shape[1]):
            if not np.array_equal(overlay[i, j], [0, 0, 0]):
                mask[i, j] = True
    result[mask] = image[mask] * 0.5 + overlay[mask] * 0.5
    return result
```

OK it works. But I don't think this is a good solution. This is terribly slow and it seems not pythonic. This takes about 5 seconds with (1024, 1024, 3) image.

Are there more efficient way? Are there along-the-axis version of array_equal in numpy? Are there internal functions exactly do this in OpenCV? Or are there more efficient algorithm?

EDIT: Above code doesn't work when color to ignore is other than black.

Comment: what would you do if the overlay has a black color somewhere ?

Comment: @Tiendung Black colored pixel will be ignored and not used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's a generalized one to take care of generic ignore-color parameter -

```
def overlay_two_image(image, overlay, ignore_color=[0,0,0]):
    ignore_color = np.asarray(ignore_color)
    mask = ~(overlay==ignore_color).all(-1)
    # Or mask = (overlay!=ignore_color).any(-1)
    out = image.copy()
    out[mask] = image[mask] * 0.5 + overlay[mask] * 0.5
    return out
```

**Approach #2**

Use `np.where` to make it more *pythonic* -

```
def overlay_two_image_v2(image, overlay, ignore_color=[0,0,0]):
    ignore_color = np.asarray(ignore_color)
    mask = (overlay==ignore_color).all(-1,keepdims=True)
    out = np.where(mask,image,(image * 0.5 + overlay * 0.5).astype(image.dtype))
    return out
```

**Approach #3**

Use `views` for memory and hence performance efficiency -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/45313353/ @Divakar
def view1D(a, b): # a, b are arrays
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    b = np.ascontiguousarray(b)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    return a.view(void_dt).ravel(),  b.view(void_dt).ravel()

def overlay_two_image_v3(image, overlay, ignore_color=[0,0,0]):
    ignore_color = np.asarray(ignore_color)
    O,I = view1D(overlay.reshape(-1,overlay.shape[-1]),ignore_color)
    mask = (O==I).reshape(overlay.shape[:2])[...,None]
    out = np.where(mask,image,(image * 0.5 + overlay * 0.5).astype(image.dtype))
    return out
```

Make use of `numexpr` module for further boost -

```
import numexpr as ne

def overlay_two_image_v3_numexpr(image, overlay, ignore_color=[0,0,0]):
    ignore_color = np.asarray(ignore_color)
    O,I = view1D(overlay.reshape(-1,overlay.shape[-1]),ignore_color)
    mask = (O==I).reshape(overlay.shape[:2])[...,None]
    scaled_vals = ne.evaluate('image * 0.5 + overlay * 0.5').astype(image.dtype)
    out = np.where(mask,image,scaled_vals)
    return out
```

Timings on a large image dataset -

```
In [250]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: image = np.random.randint(0,256,(4000,5000,3))
     ...: overlay = np.random.randint(0,256,(4000,5000,3))

In [251]: ignore_color = [56,23,90]

In [252]: m,n = image.shape[:2]
     ...: unq_idx = np.random.choice(m*n,m*n//2,replace=0)
     ...: overlay.reshape(-1,overlay.shape[-1])[unq_idx] = ignore_color

In [253]: %timeit overlay_two_image(image, overlay, [56,23,90])
     ...: %timeit overlay_two_image_v2(image, overlay, [56,23,90])
     ...: %timeit overlay_two_image_v3(image, overlay, [56,23,90])
     ...: %timeit overlay_two_image_v3_numexpr(image, overlay, [56,23,90])
1.91 s ± 8.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
1.43 s ± 8.55 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
1.3 s ± 2.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
869 ms ± 3.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

consider using [`numpy.ma`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/maskedarray.generic.html). it does the jobs faster.

in your case, try replacing

```
mask = np.full(image.shape, False)
for i in range(image.shape[0]):
        for j in range(image.shape[1]):
            if not np.array_equal(overlay[i, j], [0, 0, 0]):
                mask[i, j] = True
```

with

```
mask = np.ma.masked_greater(overlay, 0).mask
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code is much faster than mine. But I found a bug: my code doesn't work when color to ignore is not black. (For example, red: [0, 0, 255])