# given permuted arrays, find permutation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, permutation

I have two numpy integer arrays,

```py
import numpy

a = numpy.array([1, 3, 5, 0])
b = numpy.array([3, 5, 0, 1])
```

which I know are permutations of each other. How can I find the permutation, i.e., the integer array `i` such that

```
a[i] == b
```

? Explicit `for` loops with comparisons across the entire arrays works, but seems inefficient.

Bonus points if it works of permutation of row-arrays like

```py
import numpy

a = numpy.array([
   [1, 2],
   [3, 7],
   [5, 12],
   [0, 4],
   # ...
])
b = numpy.array([
   [3, 7],
   [5, 12],
   [0, 4], 
   [1, 2],
   # ...
])
```

Comment: What are typical sizes of the arrays?

Comment: Do the input arrays contain duplicate numbers?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser A few dozen to a few thousand.

Comment: @GZ Nope, it's unique.

Comment: Are there any patterns of the permutations, e.g. rotations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one using argsort twice. It seems a few percent faster than @Divakar's:

[image]

```
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder, MultiArgument
import numpy as np

B = BenchmarkBuilder()

@B.add_function()
def div(A,B):
    sidx = A.argsort()
    return sidx[np.searchsorted(A,B,sorter=sidx)]

@B.add_function()
def pp(A,B):
    oa,ob = (x.argsort() for x in (A,B))
    o = np.empty_like(oa)
    o[ob] = oa
    return o

@B.add_arguments('array size')
def argument_provider():
    for exp in range(8, 30):
        dim_size = int(1.4**exp)
        a = np.random.permutation(dim_size)
        b = np.random.permutation(dim_size)
        yield dim_size, MultiArgument([a,b])

r = B.run()
r.plot()

import pylab
pylab.savefig('bm.png')
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one with [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) on `1D`-views for `2D` arrays -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/45313353/ @Divakar
def view1D(a, b): # a, b are arrays
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    b = np.ascontiguousarray(b)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    return a.view(void_dt).ravel(),  b.view(void_dt).ravel()

A,B = view1D(a,b)
sidx = A.argsort()
idx = sidx[np.searchsorted(A,B,sorter=sidx)]
```

For `1D` input arrays, we can directly feed in `a` and `b` as `A` and `B` respectively.

Alternatively, for positive integers, we can use dimensionality-reduction with [`grid-mapping`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38674038/), keeping rest of it same as earlier -

```
s = np.r_[1,a[:,:-1].max(0)+1]
A,B = a.dot(s),b.dot(s)
```

Or use `np.ravel_multi_index` to do the mapping on 2D-grid -

```
shp = a.max(0)+1
A,B = np.ravel_multi_index(a.T,shp),np.ravel_multi_index(b.T,shp)
```

Another for positive integers with `sparse-matrix` using the same `grid-mapping` technique -

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

R = np.arange(1,len(a)+1)
c = csr_matrix((R, a.T), shape=a.max(0)+1)
idx = c[b[:,0],b[:,1]].A1-1
```